# Probably simple problem of analytically solving a system of two ODEs with given boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

While working on a physics problem I came across the following system of differential equations
$$
\dot x(t)=\frac{v(w t - x)}{\sqrt{w ^2 t^2 - 2 w t x + x^2+y^2}},
$$
$$
\dot y(t)=\frac{-v y}{\sqrt{w ^2 t^2 - 2 w t x + x^2+y^2}},
$$
where on the right hand side I omitted the explicit dependence of $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ for better readability.
The boundary conditions I wanted to consider are
$$
x(0)=0,
$$
$$
y(0)=d.
$$
Originally, I tried to solve this for arbitrary real (but constant) parameters $v$, $w$, and $d$. However, even in the special case $v=1$, $w=0$, and $d$ arbitrary I struggle to solve it analytically. In this case the system above reduces to
$$
\dot x(t)=\frac{- x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
$$
$$
\dot y(t)=\frac{- y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
$$
with the boundary conditions unchanged.

I can find the numerical solution with Mathematica for specific real parameters for the general problem.
I also have no problem in guessing the solution for the reduced problem (I can even guess that the point $(x(t)=0,y(t)=0)$ must be excluded in this case). Thus, I guess that the actual solution must be easy as well.
However, I cannot find an elegant analytic solution for either case.

Does this system of differential equations even have a (unique) solution? If so, what is the approach I am missing? I am grateful for any tips.

Comment: I guess one could view it as a kind of chase. Person 1 starts at the origin $(0,0)$ at time $t=0$ and runs along the x-axis with velocity $w$. The pursuer (person 2) is initially at the position $(0,d)$ in the x-y-plane and (at each time $t$) runs towards person 1 with velocity $v$. The question is what curve does the path of the pursuer describe. If you wish you can substitute "particle" for "person" if you want some more fundamental physics problem.

Comment: That is indeed an analogous problem to mine, described by the same maths. This perfectly answers my question. Thank you!
(Unfortunately, I cannot mark this comment as the answer.)